# SqlDataReader Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, prepared-statement

I'm trying to make SqlParameter and when I run the website error appear in `SqlDataReader _dataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();`

*Here is my code:*

```
private void goLogin()
{
   conn.ConnectionString = _connectionString;
   conn.Open();
   string username = txt_username.Text;
   _sqlCodes = "SELECT ACC_PASS,ACC_ID" +
   "FROM ACC WHERE ACC_USER = @username";
   SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand(_sqlCodes);
   _command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username",username));
   SqlDataReader _dataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();

   //more codes here...
   conn.Close();
}
```

*ERROR:*

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

**ExecuteReader:** Connection property has not been initialized.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web      request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.

**Source Error:**

```
Line 31:             SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand(_sqlCodes);
Line 32:             _command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username",username));
Line 33:             SqlDataReader _dataReader = _command.ExecuteReader();
Line 34:             conn.Close();
Line 35:         }
```

**Source File:** C:\Users\arnie.mateo\Desktop\GoWireless Project Leonel\GoWireless\GoWireless\account.aspx.cs    Line: 33

**Stack Trace:**

```
[InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: Connection property has not been initialized.]
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async) +5089605
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +87
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +32
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +141
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +89
GoWireless.WebForm1.goLogin() in C:\Users\arnie.mateo\Desktop\GoWireless Project Leonel\GoWireless\GoWireless\account.aspx.cs:33
GoWireless.WebForm1.btn_login_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\arnie.mateo\Desktop\GoWireless Project Leonel\GoWireless\GoWireless\account.aspx.cs:52
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563
```

**Version Information:** Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Comment: You need _command.Connection = conn;

Comment: No problem. Everyone has done this more times than they want to count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give connection name to `SqlCommand`.

Use `SqlCommand _command = new SqlCommand(_sqlCodes, conn);`

Answer (score 1):

The `SqlCommand` object doesn't know which connection to use.  You can create the command with:

```
SqlCommand _command = conn.CreateCommand();
```

or set the connection on it:

```
_command.Connection = conn;
```